# How can I clean up this report using LISTAGG?

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have an Oracle table storing MARC21 data broken up by field:

doc_number | field | text

I've created a sample table in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d4a1b/2).  The data itself is greatly simplified (for the 6 records, I've only included the relevant fields, all 6 of these are likely 20-30 rows long in the actual data).

I need to pull specific fields from this table based on a number of other parameters, aggregated into a single row, and eliminate rows where this aggregated text contains a key word or phrase ("Suppress display").  Using the query in the SQL Fiddle setup, I'm getting the rows I don't want (the ones with "Suppress display") in triplicate.  If I use a WHERE clause to eliminate the specific field containing the text (`WHERE field = '902' AND text LIKE 'Suppress'`), that just shortens the aggregated text and I only get double the lines instead of triple.

Query:

```
SELECT doc_number,
  LISTAGG(field || '=' || text, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY field) OVER (PARTITION BY doc_number)
FROM record
```

So A: how do I eliminate rows listed in triplicate with LISTAGG? And B: how (if possible) can I limit the query based on the aggregated text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can just select from your query and group by both columns:
[Updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/84488/7)

```
select
*
from
(
SELECT doc_number, LISTAGG(field || '=' || text, '; ') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY field) OVER (PARTITION BY doc_number) as Bob
FROM record
) t1
group by
doc_number,
bob
```

Comment: That worked. I'm not sure why I didn't think of a parent query. I can also easily use a WHERE in the parent query. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the partition and include a `group by`:

```
SELECT   doc_number,
         LISTAGG(field || '=' || text, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY field)
FROM     record
GROUP BY doc_number
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/84488/9/0

Comment: That works great at eliminating the duplicates. Can I then limit it based on the text, or does that still require a parent query as in Andrew's answer?